# Odd smoke simulation collision behaviour at resolutions above 41

Tags: smoke-simulation, collision, resolution

I have a smoke simulation setup which consists of two spherical inflow objects rotating around a common central point. Both objects stay inside of a torus shaped effector set to collision.

I have tested the simulation at a resolution of 32, saw that it worked fine and then increased the resolution to 128. However the smoke would now stay inside of a considerably smaller area when compared to before. I tested around with different resolutions (always leaving every other setting untouched) and found that this behaviour occurs on every resolution higher than 41.

The below renders all show the same frame, but are taken at a resolution of 20, 32, 41, 42, 64 and 128. One can clearly see, that the renders of resolutions below or at 41 follow the actual torus, while the ones above 41 follow the torus like it had a big margin around it. The effector itself is not visible for clarity.

Project File:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vmYjnf1QUv8O1uEQ1fcn23vcT7GD6RMu/view?usp=sharing

[image: Resolution: 20]
[image: Resolution: 32]
[image: Resolution: 41]
[image: Resolution: 42]
[image: Resolution: 64]
[image: Resolution: 128]

My settings:
[image: Settings]

Comment: I'm sorry, but just seeing a bit of green does not really clarify how you have setup the scene. And the domain's _Resolution Divisions_ are not the only criterion to decide how the smoke behaves. How are those emitters put inside the collision object? What settings do they have? How are the collision object's properties set up? In which direction are the normals oriented? At first glance it simply looks like the low resolutions are not not fine enough in detail to fully respect the boundaries of the collision object. But that's all just blind guesswork on my behalf.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I´m sorry if I did not make this clear, but the lower resolutions follow the collider exactly. You see the shape of the collider best in the third picture. The collider has its normals oriented to the inside and has a solidify modifier applied before the smoke sim. I will include pictures of my settings, but concerning your comment, that the resolution is not the only criterion for the smoke behaviour; That is the precise reason I asked this question, because the behaviour of the smoke changed drastically after an arbitrary resolution with no other setting changed.

Comment: I asked this because surely the resolution divisions have a great impact - especially when for example objects or gaps etc. are smaller or closer than what a low resolution can register. Nevertheless that's not all. The information that there is a _Solidify Modifier_ was not in the question, this also makes a difference, in a way how the boundaries of the effector are treated e.g. if you have to enable _Use Planar_. This can also influence if there is a difference in behaviour on lower resolutions for normals pointing inwards or outwards.

Comment: There is also no visible information on how much space there is between the emitters and the effector or how large this space is in relation to the voxel size determined by the _Resolution Divisions_.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Do you just want to take a look at the project file? I feel like it is going to take a lot of time to explain every setting and relation in this setup.

Comment: Well, the resolution might seem to be the only relevant parameter you are changing, but this is all connected to a lot of other aspects of the simulation and how the resolution can handle the other parameters, so probably it would be best to upload your file, yes.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Well I uploaded the project file, but for some reason I was not able to recreate the correct behaviour as seen before. The only thing I did was change the cache setting, so that the simulation starts at frame 1.